# Possible to get current location when offline for Windows Store App?

Tags: geolocation, gps, location, windows-store-apps, offline

I'm trying to find out whether it's possible to get the current location of a Windows 8 device if it's not connected to the internet via Wi-Fi. I'm aiming this at Windows 8 tablets and I don't think they all support GPS. Does anyone know what would be the best way to go about this? Or is it possible at all? Little bit lost and bombarded with solutions that don't seem helpful for my situation.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.

If theres no internet connectivity and no GPS, there is simply no way to work out where on earth you are!

What I would suggest doing is:

1) Saving the location each time you do it and using a previous location and informing the user.

2) Not doing anything and instead asking the user to turn on their GPS.

But yes, I would still *try* to find out the location even if their isn't an internet connection, because some devices will have GPS onboard and enabled.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was thinking that might be the answer. Just wondering, do you know if an internet connection isn't available, would GPS be used automatically to find the user's location? Or would I need to implement it in a different way? I've been looking around on msdn but the documentation for windows 8 isn't very complete at the moment.